# SIGABRT error in dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier:), when using custom UITableViewCell

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, sigabrt

I'm building an app with multiple scenes and a table view with custom cells in each. I got the home screen table view to work fine and then I segue to the new scene from the custom cells. When it segues, my second view controller crashes.

Here is my code for the view controller

```
import UIKit

class QuestionViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var questionLabel: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var submitButton: UIButton!
    @IBOutlet weak var qTableView: UITableView!


    var answers : [QuestionOption] = []


    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        answers = [QuestionOption(text: "test"), QuestionOption(text: "test"), QuestionOption(text: "test"), QuestionOption(text: "test")]
        qTableView.delegate = self
        qTableView.dataSource = self
        submitButton.setTitle("Submit", for: .normal)
        questionLabel.text = "test question"
    }


}

extension QuestionViewController: UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate{

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return answers.count
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let a = answers[indexPath.row]
        let cell = qTableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "QuestionOptionCell") as! QuestionOptionCell

        cell.setOption(option: a)

        return cell
    }

}
```

Here's my code for the cell

```
import UIKit

class QuestionOptionCell: UITableViewCell {

    @IBOutlet weak var cellTitle: UILabel!

    func setOption(option: QuestionOption){
        cellTitle.text = option.text
    }

}
```

Here's my code for the QuestionOption class

```
import Foundation
import UIKit

class QuestionOption{
    var text: String

    init(text: String){
        self.text = text
    }
}
```

Crash log

```
2019-02-20 14:33:28.394695-0800 iQuiz[8935:822409] *** NSForwarding: warning: object 0x7fd608407c40 of class 'iQuiz.QuestionOption' does not implement methodSignatureForSelector: -- trouble ahead
Unrecognized selector -[iQuiz.QuestionOption initWithCoder:]
2019-02-20 14:33:28.395281-0800 iQuiz[8935:822409] Unrecognized selector -[iQuiz.QuestionOption initWithCoder:]
```

Here's my storyboard if that helps at all
[image]

I've made sure my identifier matches and I don't have any extraneous or unconnected outlets, those are the only solution to this problem I can find online.

Comment: Is the class of the cell set to `QuestionOptionCell`?

Comment: Can you put a sample project on Dropbox or Github?

Comment: please add you console crash log

Comment: @qtngo https://www.dropbox.com/sh/gx2frjp52jlvj8e/AAD_Xs2Ni0vdFARVADfl5Is0a?dl=0

Comment: @kjoe I added it to the original question

Comment: @vadian yes it is

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The crash log says that `QuestionOption` must be a subclass of `NSObject` and adopt `NSCoding` which is overkill in this case. Actually a struct would be sufficient.

You can avoid it by deleting the method in `QuestionOptionCell`

```
func setOption(option: QuestionOption){
    cellTitle.text = option.text
}
```

and set the value in `cellForRowAt` directly by replacing

```
cell.setOption(option: a)
```

with

```
cell.cellTitle.text = a.text
```

Comment: That fixed it. I'm confused why it worked for my other tableview but not this one. Any ideas?

Comment: No, I haven't. And as mentioned in another answer you should always use the passed `tableView` parameter in `cellForRow` rather than the property `qTableView`.

Comment: Yeah I fixed that as well. Thanks for the help

Answer (score 1):

Things to check:

- Verify that "QuestionOptionCell" is indeed the reuse identifier for the cell.
- Verify that the selected type for the cell is `QuestionOptionCell`.
- In cellForRowAt, use `tableView.dequeueReusableCell` instead of `qTableView.dequeueReusableCell`.

Otherwise, share the crash log with us.

Comment: I don't see reuse identifier but I do see identifier and it is set to "QuestionOptionCell"